# What is this code doing? Involves character arrays and pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
unsigned char myArray[10];

myArray[0] = 0;
myArray[1] = 0;
myArray[2] = 0;
myArray[3] = 22;

cout << *((int *) (myArray)) << endl;
```

I was shown this code in a class, but it was not explained very well. I have determined that the output is equal to (256^3)*22, but I don't know why this is what it prints out. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I hope you're being taught this in a low-level programming class, where they told you that the result you get is both not guaranteed by C++ and is platform specific in part due to endian issues.

Comment: Break it up piece by piece: what is `(int *)myArray`? Then what is `*((int *)myArray)`? As Nicol Bolas mentioned, what gets printed out will depend on the system's endian-ness as well as the sizeof(int).

Comment: You must be working on an Intel machine; elsewhere (big endian systems) would print 22, if they didn't crash.  It 'works' when the array is sufficiently well aligned to be treated as an integer.  On non-Intel chips, it will probably not work if you declared a variable `char c1;` before the array and a variable `char c2;` after the array.  And it will run more slowly on an Intel machine under many compilers if you have the extra variables.  It does depend on the compiler, though.

Comment: Right, this is platform-specific code. Without knowing the platform, no answer is possible. (And it may break on different compilers and such too.)

Comment: Oh and nobody has mentioned that this is technically undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is unsafe and non-portable.

It (obviously) stores the values 0, 0, 0, and 22 in the first 4 elements of `myArray`, each of which is an `unsigned char` (a single byte).

The expression `myArray` is the name of an array, which in most contexts (including this one) "decays" to a pointer to the array's first element, of type `unsigned char*`.  The cast converts the `unsigned char*` to `int*`, and the `*` operator defererences that pointer, yielding an `int` result.

So `*((int *) (myArray))` takes the first 4 bytes of `myArray` and *reinterprets* them as an `int` object.

There are at least 3 problems with this.

1. There is no guarantee that `myArray` is correctly aligned for an `int` object.  It *probably* is, but if it isn't the behavior is undefined; you could get a bus error, or an incorrect result, or something else altogether.  (x86 processors aren't very picky about alignment, but other systems are.)
2. There is no guarantee that `sizeof (int) == 4`.  If `int` is 8 bytes, then it will reinterpret the first *8* bytes of `myArray` as an `int` -- and 4 of those bytes are garbage.
3. The representation of `int` can vary.  The main problem is byte order.  Assuming nothing else goes wrong, the result could be either 256<sup>3</sup> * 22, or 22 -- or even something else.

Answer (score 2):

The last line reinterprets the address of `myArray` as a pointer to an `int`, dereferences it, and prints it.  On 32-bit systems, `int` is four bytes long, so `myArray[0]` through my `myArray[3]` are being interpeted as the `int`. The perceived value of the `int` depends on [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).